# Regular expression for tokenize string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression to tokenize string based on a string which can be extensible in future, since I am pretty much new to regular expression, I am not able write one without an issue.

For now I have string in following pattern (Well I am trying to write a parser for a custom programming language)

```
variablename[space]:=[space]"variablevalue"; //a comment line
```

considering space is optional, I am trying to see if I can write a regular expression to parse this line like below with space omitted.

```
variablename

:=

variablevalue

//a comment line
```

Here I am trying to tokenize the line based on many thing, but if it can be simplified by writing a single regular expression then I can extend it for many other delimiters.

Comment: You said it yourself: `I am trying to write a parser`. Regexes were not made to parse, better write a *real* parser ;)

Comment: Yes :) I do understand that.. but the language is not so complex in its hood, so I am thinking of parsing using regular expression to tokenize literal and apply language grammar.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** The following do not handle all cases, such as comments, literals, etc. It is just an example of *how to write a dummy lexer*!

Using a regular expression to tokenize an expression will never be as good as writing a complete lexer (or using an existing one).

From what you have posted, you can try something like:

```
function tokenize(expr) {
  return expr.match(/(;|:=|[a-zA-Z]\w*|(["'])[^\2]*\2)/g);
}
```

Usage:

```
> tokenize("variable := 'Some expr';")
["variable", ":=", "'Some expr'", ";"]
```

You can improve the lexer by recognizing the token type:

```
function tokenize(expr) {
  return expr.match(/(;|:=|[a-zA-Z]\w*|(["'])[^\2]*\2|$)/g).map(function(token) {
    var type;
    if (!token) {
      type = 'EOF';
    } else if (token === ':=' || token === ';') {
      type = 'Punctuator';
    } else if (token[0] === '"' || token[0] === "'") {
      type = 'StringLiteral';
    } else {
      type = 'Identifier';
    };

    return {
      type: type,
      value: token
    };
  });
}
```

Which results in:

```
> tokenize("variable := 'Some expr';")
[
  {
    type: "Identifier",
    value: "variable"
  },
  {
    type: "Punctuator",
    value: ":="
  },
  {
    type: "StringLiteral",
    value: "'Some expr'"
  },
  {
    type: "Punctuator",
    value: ";"
  },
  {
    type: "EOF",
    value: ""
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks boss, I think your idea makes sense as my custom language does not have complex grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you really want to use a regular expression here:

How about this rule for ":="

```
(\w+)[ \t]*:=[ \t]*"([^"]+)"[ \t]*;[ \t]*(//.*)?
```

first subexpression will match variable name, second will match the value, third the comment line.